# Tournament play Texas hold-em

Tags: texas-hold-em, tournament

If there are 4 players left in a tourney and the shortest stacks go out on the same hand who takes the third place prize?

Answer (score 2):

The player with the most chips at the beginning of the hand takes 3rd.

On a single table the most chips at the all-in (same betting round) is also the most chips at the beginning of the hand.

On multiple tables beginning of the hand order is not always same as the all-in bet order.  Player A could go all in for $100 and player B all in for $200 on the river but player A had more chips at the beginning of the hand.

You cannot just take pot size and divide as some players may have put in chips and folded earlier.